# jetty exception and failed startup

Tags: java, spring, maven, gwt, jetty

I upgrade gwt version from `2.3 to 2.7` and some other modules.
maven build end successfully, but when I run in superDevMode get an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object of class 'com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.WebAppContextWithReload' is not of type 'org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext'. Object Class and type Class are from different loaders.
```

I haven't any idea.

Using:

- Intellij 14
- Jetty 9.3.12.v20160915
- Spring 4.3.3.RELEASE
- Servlet API 3.1.0

```
[WARN] Failed startup of context c.g.g.d.s.j.WebAppContextWithReload{/,file:/home/.../modules/core-war/target/x12/},/home/.../modules/core-war/target/x12
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object of class 'com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.WebAppContextWithReload' is not of type 'org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext'. Object Class and type Class are from different loaders.
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:323)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:281)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration.configure(JettyWebXmlConfiguration.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:468)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1237)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:162)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:740)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:632)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1054)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:413)
```

Comment: Can you add your configuration too?

Comment: what config? web.xml?

Comment: This question has a similar exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800922/jetty-env-xml-with-datasource-leads-to-failing-webappcontext-on-mvn-jettyrun  The accepted answer suggested removing the jetty-maven-plugin.

Comment: Could it be that you have some Jetty JARs in your WEB-INF/lib? Also maybe try GWT 2.8.0 that's just been released.

Comment: I removed all jetty jar files from WEB-INF/lib, but the problem didn’t solved

Comment: Share your pom.xml it could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `gwt-dev.jar` from my `WEB-INF/lib` and add a dependency to this jar file by add a path inside classpath of my ant

```
        <java classname="com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode" dir="core-war/target/" failonerror="false" fork="true">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="project.source.path"/>
            <path refid="project.class.path"/>
            <path location="${basedir}/build-conf/lib/ojdbc-11g-1.6.jar" />
            <path location="${mvn.repo.dir}org/netezza/nzjdbc/4.6/nzjdbc-4.6.jar" />
            <path location="${mvn.repo.dir}/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/${gwt.version}/gwt-dev-2.7.0.jar" />
        </classpath>
```

Answer (score 2):

The gwt-dev.jar is on the web server classpath and it should not be. Remove the gwt-dev.jar. If it's maven, provide the scope as `<scope>provided</scope>` and it will not get put into the WEB-INF/libs folder. Check the WEB-INF/libs folder for gwt-dev.jar and remove it if need be.